# Unable to edit SharePoint Online site in SharePoint Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

My organization just enrolled for O365 and have enabled SharPoint for creating sites. I have created a Site Collection and am the primary Site Collection Owner of the site. However, when I try to open the site in Designer, it asks for credentials. When I provide my organization's credentials, it says incorrect credentials. When I provide my live account credentials, it does not accept it and asks me to re-enter the credentials.

Previously it gave me an error "This feature has been disabled by your administrator". I did a registry hack and the error was gone.

Please let me know if there are any settings that need to be done at the O365 admin level to allow opening sites in SPD. At the site level, I have already enabled opening sites in SPD.

Answer (score 0):

when you say, your organization has rolled out office 365 does that mean it has active directory integration.

you can only use live accounts when the office 365/SharePoint online is just a stand-alone subscription that is mapped to your hotmail/live account. if not, you are supposed to use windows AD and here that is also the site collection admin account.

also, the logon account should be email ID which could be firstname.lastname@domainname.com ( as per the UPN value in the Active directory)

Comment: Yes, my organization has rolled out AD too. I am trying to connect via my AD credentials in SPD, but it errors out with "Invalid login id / password"

Comment: i am sure you are using the AD login name itself. SP online works in a different way.you should use email account and password. also, this depends up on the UPN value mapped in the AD for your account.  for more details : https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2015/07/office-365-why-your-upn-should-match-your-primary-smtp-address/

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. I will check the UPN value mapped in the AD with my admin.

Comment: sure, if it works then mark it as an answer so it will help others...

Answer (score 0):

Check with your administrator. If SPD was indeed disabled from Central Admin in SPO, then your **registry** hack won't get past it.

Comment: In Central Admin do you mean, Turning scripting capabilities on or off? If so they are already on.